# Resize text if it reaches div limits, and then keep it centred after resizing

Tags: html, css

Link to image of my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2gVs.jpg

Essentially, in a little html game I'm making, I want there to be somewhere to keep score. I have a div, with a background image, and then text in a span over the top of that, with size set in em. As you can see, when the score is relatively low, it fits and looks perfect. However, if the score gets too big, it just goes over the edge of the span. I'd love it if there was a way for the text to be it's current size for most of the time... except if it reached the width limits, and then it would scale down, but keeping it's vertical and horizontal alignment.

Is this possible? Cheers :)

Comment: and is there any code that you have tried,which you might wanna paste here....or shall we give you an image having the solution??? :D

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the characters of the element such as:

```
var limits = document.getElementById("characters").value.length;
```

And if it exceeds the limit then lower down the font-size using

```
if(limits > 5) {
  document.getElementById("characters").style.fontSize = "value";
}
```